# why optimizations passes doesn't work without mem2reg?

Tags: optimization, llvm, bytecode

Why i have to do this mem2reg pass in bytecode optimization for obtaining another optimization pass result's?  What's the use of mem2reg?

```
opt -dce myfile.bc
```

in this case i haven't changes in the output code

```
opt -mem2reg -dce myfile.bc
```

in this second case i have changes in the output code

edit:
LLVR IR is still into SSa form, isn't it? using mem2reg i should have a "pruned" SSA form, is right?

Comment: Well, what does the code look like? (Try running `llvm-dis` or whatever it's called.) It's quite frequent that one optimization enables another.

Comment: yes, i know this, but my question is what does mem2reg? what kind of optimization does it do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

mem2reg pass converts non-SSA form of LLVM IR into SSA form, raising loads and stores to stack-allocated values to "registers" (SSA values). Many of LLVM optimization passes operate on the code in SSA form and thus most probably will be no-op seeing IR in non-SSA form.

A bit more information is here: http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register

Comment: excuse me, but LLVR IR is still into SSa form, isn't it? in this way i should have a "pruned" SSA form, is right?

Comment: @Nicola - LLVM IR might be in SSA form and might now be (because memory is not SSA in LLVM world). So, you can easily have non-SSA LLVM IR - with alloca's loads and stores.